# Why is it necessary to have convexity outside the feasible region?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-optimization

In the book "convex optimization" by Prof. Boyd and Prof. Vandenberghe, a convex problem is defined as,

$$
\begin{equation}\label{op_prob_gen_equivalent}
\begin{aligned}
& {\text{minimise}} & &  \  f_0(x)
\\
& \text{subject to} & & f_i(x) \leqslant 0 \ , \ \quad \forall i \in \{1,2,...,m\}\\
&&& a_i^Tx=b_i \ , \ \quad \forall i \in \{1,2,...,p\}\\
\end{aligned} \quad ,
\end{equation}
$$
where $f_0(x) \ , \ f_1(x) \ , \ ... \ , \ f_m(x)$ are convex.

Let $X$ be the feasible set defined as $X=\{x| x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \ f_i(x) \leqslant 0 \  \forall i =1,2,...,m , \ a_i^Tx=b_i \ , \ \forall i =1,2,...,p \}$.

My question is, why is it necessary for $f_0(x) \ , \ f_1(x) \ , \ ... \ , \ f_m(x)$ to be convex outside $X$?

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2022295/convex-optimization-with-non-convex-objective-function

Comment: @LinAlg
Hi! Still I am curious about the question asked 
"Can we still find an example, where objective function is convex only within the feasible region, and a KKT point that does not correspond to an optimal?". Do you have a answer for this?

As you said in the link you commented 
"A point that satisfies first and second order conditions but is not optimal could be on the boundary (but not in the interior)."
Could you give an example on this?

Answer (score 7):

Frankly, it's for largely practical reasons, though as LinAlg points out below, even some theoretical results depend on convexity outside of the feasible region.

One of the most important reasons that we care about convex optimization problems is that they are theoretically tractable, and can be readily solved in practice. So now let's consider how we go about solving them.

One of the distinctions that we often make when classifying algorithms that solve convex programs is between *feasible methods* and *infeasible methods*. A *feasible method* is guaranteed to consider only points within the feasible region; an *infeasible method* makes no such guarantee. Infeasible algorithms can be easier to work with, but of course they do require convexity outside of the feasible region. On the other hand, a feasible algorithm doesn't care if your constraint functions are convex outside of the feasible region. Or does it?

The complication is that a feasible method must be *initialized* with a feasible point. If you happen to know one, you win. But if not, you must employ a *two-phase* approach. The first phase is used to find a feasible starting point for the second phase. One way to do it is to solve a model like this:

\begin{array}{lll}
\text{minimize} & z \\
\text{subject to} & f_i(x) \leq z & i= 1,2,\dots,m \\
                  & a_i^T x = b & i=1,2,\dots, p \\
                  & z \geq 0
\end{array}

The good news is that it's easy to find a feasible initial point for this problem: just choose any $x$ that satisfies the equality constraints, and set $z_i=f_i(x)$, $i=1,2,\dots, m$. With that point, you can use your standard feasible optimization method to solve this problem; and once you achieve $z=0$, you can stop and transition to phase 2.

The bad news is that, if $z>0$, you're starting outside the *original* feasible region. So you can't rely on the fact that the functions are convex just within the feasible region; they must be convex *outside* of that region, too. Indeed, we now have to guarantee that the functions are convex for all $x$ satisfying the equality constraints.

In limited circumstances, you might be able to find a way to expand your search space carefully to avoid regions of non-convexity. But the point remains that it is not sufficient to have convexity simply within the feasible region.

Comment: I think that's a fair point; I'll modify my post to be less categorical.

Comment: @LinAlg, For the example you have given, that is true. But the objective function $−x^3$ is not convex within the feasible region $x \in [0,1]$. Can we still find an example, where objective function is convex only within the feasible region, and a KKT point that does not correspond to an optimal?