# Is optimizing a convex function $f(x,y)$ that has a equality constraint $x+y=1$ a convex optimization problem?

Tags: convex-optimization

I have a convex function $f(x,y)$, with the equality constraint $x+y=1$. Is this still a convex optimization problem, despite the equality constraint? or is it a nonlinear optimization problem?

Comment: Why nonlinear? The constraint seems linear to me at least. You can always turn an equality constraint into two inequality constraints.

Comment: It's possible for an optimization problem to be both nonlinear and convex.  Your problem is convex, and depending on $f$ it might also be nonlinear.

Answer (score 2):

The standard definition of a convex optimization problem is:

> Minimize $f(x)$ subject to $x\in S$
>   where (1) $S$ is a convex set and (2) $f$ is a convex function on set $S$

- The set $(x,y)\in R^2$ with $x+y=1$ is clearly convex; hence (1) holds.
- And $f$ is convex by your statement; hence (2) holds.

Comment: Practically, $S$ needs to be represented by convex functions, and $f$ needs to be convex outside $S$ too: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2038759/why-is-it-necessary-to-have-convexity-outside-the-feasible-region

Comment: @LinAlg But can't we always just redefine $f$ to be infinity outside of $S$?  I don't see that it's necessarily important for $f$ to be convex outside of $S$.

Comment: What if you want to use an infeasible method?

Answer (score 0):

Linear equality constraints are OK in a convex optimization problem because the set of solutions to a linear system of equality constraints is convex.  When you have equality constraints involving a nonlinear function of the variables, then you're out of luck.