# Optimization of a locally convex function

Tags: convex-optimization

I have devised some function that I wish to minimize. Overall the function is not convex, but it is so on the relevant constraint set of its arguments (which is also convex). My question is now whether the overall nonconvexity of the function may render the whole problem a nonconvex one, despite the fact that optimization takes place only in some convex domain where the function is also convex. My intuition say that this shouldn’t pose a problem, but I am lacking a strict argument, let alone a proof.

any help is appreciated…

Comment: I'd say it's a duplicate of this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2038759/why-is-it-necessary-to-have-convexity-outside-the-feasible-region

Comment: Ah, no, it's not. In this case, there's an important distinction: your feasible region is nonconvex. In that case, you can find an initial feasible point without having to consider the nonconvexity of the objective at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you define your function only on the convex set of relevant arguments, then it will be a convex function, regardless of possible extensions outside this set. Methods for minimizing convex functions on convex sets will then work as advertised.

Comment: In practice it may depend on whether one is handling constraints using a barrier method (where the iterates stay within the constraint set) or a penalty method (where they may venture outside temporarily).

Comment: Thanks for your comments A.G. and Rahul, I was also thinking about penalty methods posing a problem in this case. Luckily however I am using block coordinate descent for minimization, where the parameters are guaranteed to stay inside the constraint set. So referring back to A.G.'s answer this should be an ok method, right?

Comment: @AndreasSteimer Right!

Comment: Even if you use a barrier method, you have to _find_ a feasible point first. If you can do that, you're fine, otherwise, you're back to the same nonconvex problem you had before.

Comment: In my case (which for the sake of laziness I have not mathematically defined here, sorry for that) finding a feasible point is not a problem at all. In fact, the feasible region is super simple, it just consists of the cartesian product of the set of pos. definite matrices with the nonnegative reals.